# Best C++ macro for creating a new scope

Tags: c++, macros

I have a macro

```
#define SCOPE_GUARD(GUARD, NAME,  ...) \
   for(bool __once = true; __once; /* nothing */) \
     for(GUARD NAME (__VA_ARGS__); __once; __once = false)
```

using something like this:

```
SCOPE_GUARD(std::unique_lock, lock, (some_mutex))
  do_some();
```

or

```
SCOPE_GUARD(std::unique_ptr<char>, buff, (new char[BUFFER_SIZE])) {
  *buff.get() = 0;
  GetSomeDescription(buff.get(), BUFFER_SIZE);
  Log(buff.get);
}
```

Are there similar(better) implementation of the macro, which is optimized by multiple compilers correctly.

P.S. Macro should be one, without finally macro like `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END` *(can redefine by `if (...)`)*.

**EDIT**
Simple scoupe in using codestyle is very huge.

```
{
   std::unique_lock lock (some_mutex);
   do_some();
}
```

but I want using some like this

```
SCOPE_GUARD(std::unique_lock, lock, (some_mutex)) do_some();
```

Comment: what about { ...code... } ?

Comment: yes, what about `{this is a scope}` ? Can you explain why you want to use a macro?

Comment: yup, but less readable for one line `{ std::unique_lock lock(mutex); do_some(); }`

Comment: @disable13 I generally don't trust macros, they make the code less understandable `{ ... }` is the far better idiom.

Comment: nothing stops you from placing { and } on separate lines

Comment: I do use macros, but why not just write `do {...} while(0)` ?

Comment: @Creris codestyle and git hooks  (;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do an awful lot with C++ templates and lambda expressions. It might be worthwhile to explore using them. For example, instead of using the `SCOPE_GUARD` macro, you could do something like this:

```
template <typename G, typename F, typename... A>
inline auto scope_guard(G&&, F&& f, A&&... args)
-> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(args)...))
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(args)...);
}

    scope_guard(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m), do_something);
    scope_guard(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m), [&]() {
        do_something1();
        do_something2();
        do_something3();
    });
```

If I were using straight macros, mine would probably look something like this:

```
#define UNWRAP(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define SCOPE_GUARD(X, Y) do { X; UNWRAP Y; } while (0)

    SCOPE_GUARD(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m), (do_something()));
    SCOPE_GUARD(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m), (
        do_something1();
        do_something2();
        do_something3();
    ));
```

Comment: this macro can't redefine by `if (...)`

Comment: but lambda is great and better idea!

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "redefine by if", and what it is about the macro that prevents you from making its action conditional.

Comment: for example using this macro like decorator for function. `void do_some() SCOPE_GUARD() { do_also_some(); }`

Comment: Wouldn't your for loop version also fail?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
#define PROTECTED_BY(m) for(std::unique_lock<decltype(m)> _lock_(m) ; _lock_ ; _lock_.unlock())
```

complete use case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

#define PROTECTED_BY(m) for(std::unique_lock<decltype(m)> _lock_(m) ; _lock_ ; _lock_.unlock())

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mutex m;

    PROTECTED_BY(m)
    {
        cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this macro woks only if `operator bool()` overloaded. if I using class without overloading? `for (FOO f; true; /* nothing */)`. May be better `for(std::unique_lock<FOO> f = new FOO(); f.get() != nullprt; f.reset(nullptr))`

Comment: Check the documentation for unique_lock. Operator bool is mandated by the standard. The macro is correct.